# Django __range function with date only returning first date

Tags: django, date, django-models

I want to return all `Source` objects within a date range, and the current query I have is

`sources = Source.objects.filter(datetime__range=(date(2013, 5, 15), date(2013, 5, 20)))`.

However, the returned `sources` list only contains items from 2013-5-15. Any idea why this is happening? Sorry for the following code dump.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

import os
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
from .models import Source
from datetime import date
from .utils import df_to_geojson

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    sources = Source.objects.filter(datetime__range=(date(2013, 5, 15), date(2013, 5, 20)))
    print('number of points: {}'.format(len(sources)))
    print(sources)
    sources_df = pd.DataFrame(list(sources.values()))
    source_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(sources_df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(sources_df['lon'], sources_df['lat']))

    points = df_to_geojson(sources_df, ['temp_BB', 'area'], 'lat', 'lon')
    print(sources_df.head())

    defaultLon = -3.1883
    defaultLat = 55.9533

    return render(request, 'geoApp/home.html', {
        'points': points,
        'lon': defaultLon,
        'lat': defaultLat,
    })
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.conf import settings
import os
import csv
import pytz
from decimal import Decimal

# Create your models here.
class Source(models.Model):
    id_key = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=40, unique=True, null=True)
    lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=6, default=999999)
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=6, default=999999)
    temp_BB = models.IntegerField()
    area = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=6, default=999999)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    radiant_heat_intensity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=6, default=999999)
    radiant_heat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=6, default=999999)
```

Comment: Do you have other dates in your Database...?? Please show a snippet of that...

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha Sorry but what do you mean? Like an actual entry in the database?